# jQuery two-way data binding + Saving and loading to/from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to accomplish two way data binding using only jQuery..
From my research it seems pretty simple and straighforward to achieve, using these links:

http://www.lucaongaro.eu/blog/2012/12/02/easy-two-way-data-binding-in-javascript/

and

http://johnpolacek.github.io/jquery-databinding/

Now my question is in the realm of saving this data. Let's suppose I have a list of elements (a task list for example) bound to a json object. I then want to save it to the database, all good. But let's say the user returns to the page and I want to re-create their list and bound element..

What would be a good optimized way to do this? I thought of getting the JSON string from the database then outputting it to the page and run a javascript foreach loop to build and populate the element.. but it seems a bit.. hum.. hackish..

How would you guys do it?